# cytoscape.js - how to merge attributes of the same node from different sources

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I have a working graph which displays some nodes & their attributes. Then I get a JSON with different data, where some nodes may already exist on my graph. How to combine both data sources, to make them both visible on the same graph - **BUT** nodes with the same **ID** must be combined into one and contain attributes from **both** data sources (not just from one, as is by default)?

Example:

```
Node from source 1 => "id": "1", "name": "1", "param1": 100;
Node from source 2 => "id": "1", "name": "1", "param2": 200;
```

What I wish to see on the graph is one node with attributes:

```
"id": "1", "name": "1", "param1": 100, "param2": 200
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm in the middle of writing code in my own application to do exactly what you're asking. The code below works, though I suspect that it's not the most efficient way. So, please don't accept this answer without waiting at least a few days for someone more experienced to post a better answer or to add a comment criticizing this answer.

The trick is to [query](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.getElementById) `cy` (the cytoscape.js core object) for a "[collection object](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.$)" containing just the node with the given id, and then query the collection object to see if it's [empty](https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.empty). If the node doesn't exist, you [`cy.add()`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.add) it. If the node does exist, you call [`node.data()`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.data) on the collection object to update it.

```
function updateGraph(g) {  // g is the output from JSON.parse(), containing graph from server
  gg = g;  // save pointer to g, for console debugging

  // Import nodes from server graph
  for (const sn of g.nodes) {  // sn = node as represented on the server
    var node = cy.$id(sn.id)   // node = cytoscape.js's representation of node
    if (node.empty()) {
      node = cy.add({group: 'nodes', data: {
        id: sn.id,
        label: sn['display-name'],  // peculiar to my application
        parent: sn.memberOf         // peculiar to my application
        /* . . . and whatever other data you want to copy to the cytoscape.js graph . . . */
      }});
      node.addClass(sn.class);
    } else {
      /* Update `node` with data from `sn`.*/
      node.data( /* your overriding data goes here */ );
    }
  }
}

var gg; // We save the last graph dict from the server here so we can look at
        // it in the Chrome debugger even after updateGraph() returns.
```

The `gg` variable isn't necessary, of course, but I've found it indispensible for seeing what's going on in the Chrome debugger.

In your application, you might be able to call [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge the data before calling `node.data()`. That would be simpler and more efficient than my code above, where data from the source has different keys than the keys expected by cytoscape.js.

Answer (score 1):

```js
     //Node from source 1 => "id": "1", "name": "1", "param1": 100;

    var xNode={"id": "1", "name": "1", "param1": 100}

    //Node from source 2 => "id": "1", "name": "1", "param2": 200;
    var  yNode={"id": "1", "name": "1", "param2": 200}

   // finalNode=Object.assign({},xNode,yNode)
   var  finalNode={...xNode,...yNode}

   console.log('merge Obj:'+JSON.stringify(finalNode))
```